# router.beforeEach working only with router-link

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am trying to change dynamically the meta tag with Vue router and it is working, I followed [this article](https://alligator.io/vuejs/vue-router-modify-head/). The problem is that it works only if I change the route from a `router-link` if I enter directly the URL the first load page wouldn’t take the dynamic meta tag.

Is there a way to run this navigation guard also when I enter directly the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and I solved it creating the instance after the `router.beforeEach`.

So it should be in this order that:

• create the `new VueRouter`

• do the `router.beforeEach`

• create the new instance `new Vue`